# How to compare different dataframes by column and row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have two csv files with 200 columns each. The two files have the exact same numbers in rows and columns. I want to compare each columns separately.

The idea would be to compare column 1 value of file "a" to column 1 value of file "b" and check the difference and so on for all the numbers in the column (there are 100 rows) and write out a number that in how many cases were the difference more than 3.

I would like to repeat the same for all the columns.
Thanks in advance!

---

```
 import pandas as pd
    dk = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/D/1_top_a.csv', sep=',', header=None)
    dk = dk.dropna(how='all')
    dk = dk.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
    print(dk)
    
    dl = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/D/1_top_b.csv', sep=',', header=None)
    dl = dl.dropna(how='all')
    dl = dl.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
    print(dl)
    
    rows=dk.shape[0]
    print(rows)
    for i
    print(dk._get_value(0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `iloc` attribute of a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

dk = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/D/1_top_a.csv', sep=',', header=None)
dk = dk.dropna(how='all')
dk = dk.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
print(dk.head())

dl = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/D/1_top_b.csv', sep=',', header=None)
dl = dl.dropna(how='all')
dl = dl.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
print(dl.head())


for row in range(len(dl)):
    for col in range(len(dl.columns)):
        if dl.iloc[row, col] != dk.iloc[row, col]:
            print(dk.iloc[row, col])
```